# Как сделать переход с формы на форму?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Вот у меня два перехода на разные формы, и я вообще не могу понять в чем причина. **MyForm** не видит попросту остальные формы.

```
private: System::Void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 this->Hide();
                 MyForm^ f = gcnew MyFormRus();
                 f->Show();
    }
    private: System::Void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             this->Hide();
             MyForm^ f = gcnew MyFormUkr();
             f->Show();
```

Comment: Так как стоит тег C#, вот на этот язык и переходите. Компилятор шарпа не требует явного включения файлов друг в друга.

Comment: Да? Тогда ладно, формы делаю на плюсах, уже убрала тег